# How do MACs provide authenticity?

Tags: authentication

I don't see how they're different then hash functions. Couldn't Alice use Bob's key to produce a MAC and send the message to Jim.

Comment: Do you mean a HMAC?

Comment: MAC addresses don't provide any authenticity at all. Where did you read that they do?

Comment: [Whats the difference between MAC vs hash](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/whats-the-difference-between-mac-vs-hash) is closely related, although this question appears to be asking about a specific scenario involving three parties.

Comment: @darkf Perhaps from its very name? It's an *authentication* code after all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yeah, my bad, I misunderstood the question and thought he was talking about MAC addresses! Thursday mornings eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean Message Authentication Code.

The major difference between a MAC and a hash function is that the MAC also takes a secret key as input. Therefore the MAC provides both integrity and authenticity for the message.

Example how it is used:

Both Alice and Bob know the secret key k. Alice wants to send an arbitrary long message m.

1. She generates a tag. tag <- S(k,m).
2. She sends message m together with the tag.

Bob verifies this.

1. V(k,m,tag) = Yes/No